# Spreadsheet add-on Auth Error - document owner and active user do not match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

in my spreadsheets add-on I have a check for document owner:

```
  var USEREMAIL = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner().getEmail();
    if (USEREMAIL == owner) {
      menu.addItem('Owner menu', 'ownermenu');
      menu.addToUi();
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Not owner', 'notowner');
      menu.addToUi();
    }
```

It is also a fallback for known problem where users are logged into multiple accounts. So I recently found out, that even if I'm a document owner and I'm only signed into one account, I still get Not owner menu.

The problem can be fixed with add-on reinstallation, but still, is it a Google bug? I don't see an obvious reason why it works properly after reinstallation, shouldn't be an issue on my side then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner's email address is [not available](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail) in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e).

Therefore the call to getOwner would return a null inside onOpen.

Comment: Amit, thanks for the quick follow up. Can you please confirm, only getOwner().getEmail(); is not working in onOpen(e) or getEffectiveUser().getEmail(); is not working as well?